# Whether to support rendering multiple attributes at the same time?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, geometry, shader-nodes

For example, if I'd like to render Normal/Parametric in Geometry, Generated/UV in Texture Coordinate, View Z Depth in Camera Data,

[image]

I am currently rendering one by one, is there any more convenient and faster way?

[image]

There are currently two questions:

1. I don't know how to forbid the default `/tmp/.png` output, so there will be many unnecessary export operations(larger images take longer to export, but for `/tmp/.png` this is wasteful):

```
Saved: '...'       # [This is what I need]
Saved: '/tmp/.png' # [This is what I don't need]
```

2. I can check the options in `Cycles`, but it is too slow, I only need to use `Eevee`(some geometric properties are not affected by the material, so there is no need for a Cycles engine)

[image]

Comment: Do [AOV passes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/output/aov.html) go some way to helping you out?

Comment: I upload an image [here](https://ibb.co/SNmf7Vn). When I test "Generated" in "Texture Coordinate" with a "Human Mesh", I found a slight difference between two settings: Left(Generated >> Emission >> Material Output) and Right(Generated >> AOV Output). Most of the pixel values are slightly different(i.e.: 0.1888,0.6513,0.4644>>0.1880,0.6538,0.4656), and the values of some pixels are quite different(not found in the default Cube and Monkey). What may be the cause of this phenomenon?

Comment: I can't be sure... curious. Is there a difference between _Generated > Material Output_ and _Generated > AOV_ ? (Skipping all use of _Emission_)

Comment: The result is the same as before. [Link](https://rec.ustc.edu.cn/share/e659f7b0-4abd-11ec-bc47-eb098d75ccea) to the testing file.    [Here](https://ibb.co/KF65WfH) is a comparison of results. I choose "Texture Coordinate"(the result is between 0~1 and can be converted to color) and do a bbox-based transformation to restore the point cloud. The result of "Material" is correct, but the result of "AOV" has two problems: the first one is outlier, the second is the value of some rows to be the same, and the restored point cloud is incorrect(staircase effect).

Comment: Hi .. Thanks for the further link.. I haven't forgotten you.. will check it out if no one else gets there first :) I t is a bit of a mystery..

Comment: I have updated the test [file](https://rec.ustc.edu.cn/share/6f9369a0-4b86-11ec-916e-9f4fe9699acf) with code for restoring the point cloud.

Comment: I'm not coming up with any convincing reason yet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AOV passes are the way to go (Edit: Actually View Layers might be the way to go).

The reason why you have artifacts in the AVO pass is because of numerical precision limitations.

I did two things to fix the problems you encountered in the file you provided.

First, I set the near and far clipping values for the camera to fit the character better and maximize the precision.
Your values were (Start: 0.01 m, End: 10000 m).
I set them to (Start: 2 m, End: 2.5 m).

Minor note: You can enable the viewport display limits in the camera properties to visualize the clipping values.

Second, I increased the number of render samples from 64 to 256.

With these two changes, the two EXR files generated by your Blend file now appear to be <strike>identical</strike> close enough for most purposes.

[image: The Changes]

(EDIT)

Since it appears there are still minor discrepancies, allow me to propose another solution.

Another way to tackle your problem is by using view layers. You can assign materials to linked duplicate objects and render each to a separate view layer. An in depth explanation for how to set it up can be found here: [Material Overrides for view layers (per object)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154321/material-overrides-for-view-layers-per-object).

[image: This is how it looks in the compositor.]

Comment: This method should work, and I'll implement it as a script. Two related videos: [Blender 2.8 Beginner Tutorial : Collections, View Layers and render layers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOO3K1B9vgg&ab_channel=ArtInMotionStudios), [Blender 2.8 Tutorial: View Layers and Render Layers as separate images](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPneC8b6gnU&ab_channel=StevenScott)  ||  PS: 1. How to forbid '/tmp/.png' in script. 2. How to feed back the inconsistency of AOV and Material results in order to help more people who need numerical accuracy? AOV seems to be more convenient for scripting.

Comment: PS: 3. Another reason for using AOV may be that the `Material Overide` in the `Multi View Layer` needs to be performed in `Cycles`, but for speed, `Eevee` is what I need.

Comment: Answer to PS1: `bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=False)`